# elasticsearch: decide which query should run first

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a simple web page, where the user can provide some input and query the database. We currently use mongodb but want to migrate to elasticsearch, since the queries are faster.

There are some required search fields, like start and end date, and some optional ones, like a search string to match an entry, or a parent search string, to match parent entries. Parent-child relations are just described through fields containing each entry's ancestors ids.

The question is the following: If both search and parent search string are provided, is there a way to know before executing the queries, which query should be executed first, in order to provide results faster and to be more performant?

For example, it could be that a specific parent search results in only 2 docs/parent entries, and then we can fetch all children matching the search string. In that case we should execute firstly the parent query and then the entry query.

One option would be to get the count of both queries and then execute first the one with the smallest count, but isn't this solution worse, since the queries are going to be executed twice? Once for the count and once for the actual query.

Are there any other options to solve this?

PS. We use elasticsearch v1.7

**Example**

Let's say the user wants to search for all entries matching the following fields.

searchString: `type:BLOCK AND name:test`

parentSearchString: `name:parentTest AND NOT type:BLOCK`

This means that we either have to

1. fetch all entries (parents) matching the `parentSearchString` and store their ids. Then, we have to fetch all entries that match the `searchString` and also have to contain any of the parent ids in the `ancestors` field.

OR

2. fetch all entries that match the `searchString` and store all `ancestors` ids. Then fetch all entries that match the `parentSearchString` and their id is one of the `ancestors` ids.

Just to clarify, both parent and children entries have the exact same structure and reside in the same index. We cannot have different indices since the pare-child relation can be 10 times nested, so an entry can be both a parent and a child. An entry looks more or less like:

```
{
  id: "e32452365321",
  name: "name",
  type: "type",
  ancestors: "id1 id2 id3" // stored in node as an array of ids
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise you, to upgrade your Elasticsearch version, if possible. There happened a lot since 1.7 and to be honest, I can't tell if all of what's written in the following article is valid for such an old version (probably it isn't).

But to your actual question: Hopefully I am understanding you correctly, but you try to estimate how costly a query for Elasticsearch is? Well, you don't have to. If you provide all 'queries' in one nested query, Elasticsearch will do that for you: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order

Regarding speed, there is one other thing I can mention: calculating score does take time. So if sorting is not based on the elasticsearch _score, you want to use boolean filter queries. This would also apply, if you want to sort only by _score of parent matches, then you could put the query for children into a filter.

---

**update**

Thanks to your example, I now see the problem. Self referencial Parent-Child relations are unfortunately [not supported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11432) by ElasticSearch, so your approach is probably right. You might want to check out the short chapter of the documentation about [application-joins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/application-joins.html).

So yes, in general, you want to send the second query with the least possible amount of ids/terms. While getting counts for both queries is not as bad as you might think, because the results are most likely still cached, does it actually help? Because if you're going from child to parent, you would have to count the ancestors (field values), and not the actual document count.

I would argue, that the most expensive operation is very often fetching result source from disk. So whichever way you go, you probably should only fetch what you need in the first query. So your options are:

- Fetch only the id of parent matches, and then use a [terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html) on `ancestors` in the second query.
- Or, fetch only the ancestors field of child matches, and use an [id filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) in your second query.

Unfortunately, I can't help you more than that, since I don't have enough experience in comparing speed of those approaches. My guess would be, that an id filter might be faster in general. But that's just a guess...

Comment: It's not quite easy for us to update elastic, so I have to work with that for now. If I also understand you well, I don't think I can have both queries in one nested query, since to write each query I would need the results from the other one. For example, if I do the parents query first, the children query would have to have a filter on the parents ids. And I read somewhere that this isn't currently available in elastic

Comment: Seems like I don't quite understand your search. Could you maybe provide a simplified example in your opening post? Maybe in SQL, if that's simpler to express. I will then try to update my answer accordingly. If your search is not overly complicated (which I assume, because you have a 'simple web page'), I still think it can be done within a single query.

Comment: I added a small example

Comment: I have updated my post. I'm afraid, I probably can't give you a proper answer, but hopefully these information/thoughts can help you in some way.